# How to set value in field using FlaUI?

Tags: powershell, ui-automation, flaui

How do I use [FlaUI](https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI) to set the value in a specific field after clicking the "Save As" button in Paint?

I'm trying to use FlaUI to automate filling a field in Paint after clicking "Save As". The field in question is named "Name:". Here is the code I have so far:

```
Add-Type -Path C:\Users\sergi\assemblies\bin\Release\net48\publish\FlaUI.UIA3.dll

$windowTitle = 'Untitled - Paint'
$control = 'Name:'
$automation = [FlaUI.UIA3.UIA3Automation]::new()
$process = get-process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -match $windowTitle}
$app = [FlaUI.Core.Application]::Attach( $process )

foreach( $wnd in $app.GetAllTopLevelWindows( $automation ) ) {
    $myinput = $wnd.FindAllDescendants() | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $control }
    $myinput[0].SetValue('Value Test')
}
```

After running the code it gives this error:

```
Method invocation failed because [FlaUI.Core.AutomationElements.AutomationElement] does not contain a method named 'SetValue'.
On line: 11 character: 5
+ $saveButton[0].SetValue('Value Test')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

However, I'm having a hard time finding a way to access this particular field and set its value using FlaUI. Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After pressing the "save" button, you have to search for the "save" dialog window. There might be a delay before the dialog and its child elements have been created, so for reliability a loop should be used.

I recommend to install [Accessibility Insights for Windows](https://accessibilityinsights.io/docs/windows/overview/) to get an idea what you need to search for. It shows you the hierarchy of automation objects and their properties.

Here is working code to automate the "save" dialog.

```sh
$automation = [FlaUI.UIA3.UIA3Automation]::new()

foreach( $process in Get-Process mspaint ) {
    $app = [FlaUI.Core.Application]::Attach( $process )

    foreach( $wnd in $app.GetAllTopLevelWindows( $automation ) ) {

        $saveButton = $wnd.FindAllDescendants() | 
                      Where-Object { $_.ControlType -eq 'Button' -and $_.Name -eq 'Save' }         

        Write-Host "Found 'save' button"

        $saveButton.Patterns.Invoke.Pattern.Invoke()

        Write-Host 'Waiting for "save" dialog...'

        $saveDialog = $fileNameField = $null

        # Loop until the "save" dialog has been shown and accepts input
        while( $true ) {
            $saveDialog = $wnd.FindAllChildren() | Where-Object Name -eq 'Save as'
            if( $saveDialog -and $saveDialog.IsEnabled ) {
                Write-Host 'Found "save" dialog'

                # Search for the file name edit control
                $fileNameField = $saveDialog.FindAllDescendants() | 
                                 Where-Object { $_.ControlType -eq 'Edit' -and $_.AutomationId -eq '1001' -and $_.IsEnabled }
                if( $fileNameField ) {
                    Write-Host 'Found file name text field'
                    break
                }
            }
            Start-Sleep 1
        }

        $savePath = 'C:\test\paint.png'

        # Delete any existing file so we can check if mspaint has saved the file
        $savePath | Where-Object { Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf } | Remove-Item -Force

        # Enter the path into the file name edit control
        $fileNameField.Patterns.Value.Pattern.SetValue( $savePath )

        # Find and press the OK button
        $okButton = $saveDialog.FindAllChildren() | 
                    Where-Object { $_.ControlType -eq 'Button' -and $_.AutomationId -eq '1' }
        $okButton.Patterns.Invoke.Pattern.Invoke()

        # Wait until file has been saved by mspaint
        while( -not ( Test-Path $savePath ) ) {
            Start-Sleep 1
        }
        Write-Host "File has been saved!"
    }
}
```